# Why are these electric circuit transformations giving me different answers? (See details)

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I used star to delta and delta to star transformation on different parts of circuit.But I am getting different answers. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is with the wire on the far left, the one that is bent, in parallel with the 4Ω.  I assume you forgot that that wire removes the 4Ω resistor by shorting it.

So if you short the 4Ω resistor on the far left (as you should), then you get
 $$8Ω || 4Ω || 1Ω = \frac{8}{11}Ω$$

Comment: So the transformation was right. Now I know the correct way of doing it. Thanks to You.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the correct answer is 0.727272 ohms or 8/11 ohms as per your second circuit but it's a lot simpler when you look at the picture:

[image]

- R1 is directly across the a and b terminals so that's easy
- R2 is in parallel with R3 so that's easy
- R2||R3 is in series with R4 so that's easy

> I used star to delta and delta to star transformation on different
>   parts of circuit.But I am getting different answers. Why is it so?

Your star/delta transformation method is flawed - re-check it.

Comment: what's wrong in first circuit?

Comment: @SajjalRana down voting my answer is not going to get you any friends here so I would ask you to think about that action. I've confirmed the correct answer so now your problem has halved i.e. you now know that the star/delta transform you used in your first circuit is faulty. I cannot say what is wrong in your first circuit other than what I've already said because YOU haven't provided the steps you took. Please don't down vote out of ignorance. I'm here to help and I give my time freely but not to people who show disrespect.

Comment: If you have not down voted my answer then sorry for misinterpreting your actions.

Comment: @Andyaka I downvoted because you haven't answered the question *properly*. Your answer is "*Your star/delta transformation method is flawed - re-check it.*".

Comment: @HarrySvensson the OP has performed two transformations and it is clear that one is wrong so pointing that out (in the absense of calculations) is all I can (and should) do. What would you suggest is a proper answer?

Comment: @Andyaka Like mine, one that pinpoints the exact error. - But it's okay, I'll remove the down vote. Well.. after some edit has happened, can't remove it until then.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Your answer is of course pin-pointing the error in the analysis and clearly I never ventured to go down that line but, it should not mean that my answer attracts a down vote from you or anyone. I confirmed the correct answer by offering a suitable alternative solution and therefore pointed out which conversion was faulty. I think you should re-consider your actions here.

Comment: @Andyaka I am grateful that you gave some of your time and answered my question and I didn't downvote your answer.(But I think you already know that by now). Thank You

Comment: @SajjalRana yes, sorry about my tirade!